# Checkbox in views

Tags: views

How to bring the input type as check box for a field .

I ve used Global:Custom Text and in that field I gave like this in text

```
<div class="cmp-button"><input type="checkbox" name="product-compare" value="123"> Compare</div>
```

but i din get the check box .. any solution please

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution, printing a checkbox in your view... What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

you need to install Views [PHP module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) then go to your view and add global PHP field then add your code it will work

Comment: The main thing is that i should'nt use global php for it . that is what it very risky for me

Comment: no problem you can use Global: Text area field and select full HTML formmat also it will work

Comment: Sorry ,do we have text area in add fields ?.I suppose it has only in header or footer n views

Comment: yes you are right but if you want you can use Bulk operation then select your operation from default bulk operation
note: if you explain what you are going to do maybe can help you in more effective way

Comment: actually i ve used global php field and used the code which i listed above i ve hidden the field and used that pattern in my another field say nid , but now my requirement is to use the same operation without using global PHP

Comment: what do you think about using  {Pass ids as arguments to a page} as bulk operation

Comment: sry can u brief it out please?

Comment: add new field as [Bulk operations: Content]
then select from SELECTED BULK OPERATIONS{Pass ids as arguments to a page}

Answer (score 0):

I dont see how placing a checkbox in a text field will help you?

If you need people to be able to edit nodes directly from a views output, then try the [editable fields module](https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields).

In the content type, add a CCK boolean or list field with your options, then add that field into your view, and format the field as "editable".

That field can now be changed directly in the view, and can save automatically with ajax if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use check boxes for multiple operation(s). You can do that with [Views Bulk Operation](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module, install and add field **bulk operations** in views.